# What does it refer to in the sentence?

Tags: pronouns

The original text:

> It is no accident that the twentieth century should be the century of
>   highly centralized governments and totalitarian dictatorships; **it**
>   had to be so for the simple reason that the twentieth century is the
>   century of planetary overcrowding.

My question is on the boldfaced "**it**." I would like to confirm "**it**" refers to "**the twentieth century**" in the first sentence and "**so**" refers to "**the century of highly centralized governments and totalitarian dictatorships**."

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct. "It" refers to the subject of the previous half of this compound sentence: *"the twentieth century"*. "So" refers to what the author describes as a characteristic of that century (*"highly centralized governments"*, etc.).

Side note:  It would be confusing if "it" did *not* refer to the previous subject, because the sentence is structured as a kind of *parallel argument*, i.e.:

> A is B, because A is C.

This is really more about logic than English.  Writers obviously can make up sentences in which the logic is vague or impenetrable, but in any language this would be considered poor writing style.   Except, perhaps, with classic Philosophy, in which it's considered *customary*.

Answer (score -1):

This "**it**" is often called a "dummy subject". It causes a lot of confusion for people learning English, because "**it**", when used in this way, doesn't refer specifically to another noun in the paragraph like "**it**" used in the typical way. You might want to read up on this usage [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/dummy-subjects), or look up "dummy subjects", and you will find many discussions of this special use of the word "**it**".

Comment: Yes, "it" is often the *dummy* or *existential* pronoun, but not in this case.  Or rather, the first "it" is the dummy pronoun, but the second "it" is not.